# Managing files in iOS5

Tags: ios, save, wrapper, file-sharing, uidocument

I want to handle files in my iOS App.
My app should create a file with a custom suffix (e.g. file.mysuff) and save it to the device so I'll be able to copy it using iTunes File Sharing.
Then I want to be able to attach that file to a new mail.
When the receiver opens the document, mail should launch my app and handle that file.

Are there good tutorials on that topic?
I'm still quite new to cocoa / cocoa touch so it should be easy to my.
Is maybe a wrapper out there that I could implement so I just have to code something like

`[self [saveMyFile path:[NSURL] contents:[NSString]]]`??

Thanks for help!
Greets, J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one example of how you can save the file to documents on the iPhone to use later. This stores a dictionary from a list, changes a value and then writes the updates dictionary back to the file specified. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```
//user document directory and instantiate dictionary
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistFilePathInDocumentsDirectory = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile"];
    NSMutableDictionary *yourList= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePathInDocumentsDirectory];

//save the new information to the plist in the user documents directory
    [yourList setObject:someObject forKey:someKey];
    [yourList writeToFile:plistFilePathInDocumentsDirectory atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I don't really know, if this is what I'm looking for. I won't use plist files. I also want a custom file format. Something like a plain textfile with my own suffix. And when the user klicks on a file of that type (e.g. in Mail), it should launch my app. Where exactly is that Path?

Comment: I edited the code a bit and now it fits perfectly for my needs. Thank you a lot, great help! :))